# row function in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I am using SAS EG to do this.
This is the input table that I have:

```
ref11  ref2  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4 Col5 Col6
 A     B     41          42              
 D     E           63    65         68
 X     Y     23    25    55         89   99
 K     L     12                22
 U     V                 22    88        11
```

I am trying to get the output as

```
R1  R2  C1  C2  C3  C4 C5 C6
 A   B  41  42              
 D   E  63  65  68
 X   Y  23  25  55  57 89 99
 K   L  12  22
 U   V  22  88  11
```

so basically my reference is ref1 and ref2 and I want to get rid of the blanks for each reference. For example- for A B, col2 is blank so the value of col3 should move to col2.

this is the code that I have right now.

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE output AS

SELECT ref1 as R1,
       ref2 as R2,
       (CASE WHEN col1 <> '' THEN col1 ELSE (CASE WHEN col2 <> '' THEN col2 ELSE (CASE WHEN col3 <> '' THEN col3 ELSE
       (CASE WHEN col4 <> '' THEN col4 ELSE (CASE WHEN col5 <> '' THEN col5 ELSE (CASE WHEN col6 <> '' THEN col6 ELSE '' END) 
       END) END) END) END) END) AS C1,

       (CASE WHEN col2 <> '' AND col1 <> '' THEN col2 ELSE (CASE WHEN col3 <> '' THEN col3 ELSE
       (CASE WHEN col4 <> '' THEN col4 ELSE (CASE WHEN col5 <> '' THEN col5 ELSE (CASE WHEN col6 <> '' THEN col6 ELSE '' END) 
       END) END) END) END) AS C2,

      (CASE WHEN col3 <> ''  AND col2 <> ''  AND col1 <> '' THEN col3 ELSE (CASE WHEN col4 <> '' THEN col4 ELSE 
      (CASE WHEN col5 <> '' THEN col5 ELSE (CASE WHEN col6 <> '' THEN col6 ELSE '' END) END) END)END) AS C3,

      (CASE WHEN col4 <> '' AND col3 <> '' AND col2 <> '' THEN col4 ELSE (CASE WHEN col5 <> '' THEN col5 ELSE (CASE WHEN col6 <> '' THEN col6 ELSE '' END) 
       END) END) AS C4,

      (CASE WHEN col5 <> '' AND col4 <> '' AND col3 <> '' AND col2 <> '' THEN col5 ELSE (CASE WHEN col6 <> '' THEN col6 ELSE '' END) 
       END)AS C5

FROM input;
```

### QUIT;

this is what I get.

```
R1  R2  C1  C2  C3  C4 C5 
 A   B  41  42  42  42              
 D   E  63  65  68  68 
 X   Y  23  25  55  89 99 
 K   L  12  22  22  22
 U   V  22  88  11  11 11
```

this code doesn't give me the exact result that I want and I also think that there should be an easier way to do this. Please advice.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://support.sas.com/kb/24/663.html

Comment: Thanks JT85. This code works great. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below the code that worked. Solution provided by JT85.

```
set test;
  array in col1-col6;
  array out $ c1-c6;
  j=1;
  do i=1 to 5;
    if in(i) ne ' ' then do;
      out(j)=in(i);
      j+1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[assuming the order of the values is not important as long as the missing values are to one side and non-missing values to another] You could use the [`call sortn`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003106054.htm) routine. `call sortn` essentially sorts values that are in columns in the same way that `PROC SORT` sorts rows.

```
data have;
input ref1 $ ref2 $ col1-col6;
datalines;
 A B 41 . 42 . . .
 D E . 63 65 . 68 .
 X Y 23 25 55 . 89 99
 K L 12 . . 22 . .
 U V . . 22 88 . 11
 ;
 run;

DATA WANT;
SET have;
ARRAY myVars{6} col6-col1;
call sortn(of myVars(*));
run;

/*note the reversed col6-col1, this is because sortn only does
   ascending order sort, if we want descending then array variables must be specified in reverse order*/
```

Comment: other than numbers, I do have some alphanumeric characters like AB46 etc. and characters like HHD etc. Sorry for not mentioning but col1-col6 may contain alphanumeric characters as well.

Comment: CALL SORTC would work on character variables.  (The actual contents isn't important; what is important is whether they are numeric or character formatted cells.)

Comment: Also, I like the reverse order trick - clever solution to the descending sort.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some clever trick, but on first sight, i would work with arrays.

```
data OUTPUT (drop=i j);
    set INPUT;
    array c_array{6} Col1-Col6;
    do i=1 to 6;
        /*if missing, look further in the array for a value*/
        if missing(c_array{i}) then do;
            do j=i+1 to 6 by 1;
                /*if a value is found, copy it to the empty location, then erase it from the original spot*/
                if not missing(c_array{j}) then do;
                    c_array{i} = c_array{j};
                    c_array{j} = .;
                    leave; /*stop the loop, we found what we needed*/
                end;
            end;
            /*if you did not find anything, it is pointless to continue for the remainder of the array*/
            if missing(c_array{i}) then leave;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

I left out the rename statement you would need to write to go from ColX to CX, but i hope that that detail is obvious enough. ;)

Comment: This indeed looks more like the SAS -way to do it.

Comment: The only issue I got in my output is for the scenario when there are two empty cells in between. Like  K L 12 . . 22 . .      the output that i get is  K L 12 . 22 . . But this code works great...data shifted (drop=v1-v5 j i);
  set test;
  array in v1-v5;
  array out $ o1-o5;
  j=1;
  do i=1 to 5;
    if in(i) ne ' ' then do;
      out(j)=in(i);
      j+1;
    end;
  end;
run;   thank You wildplasser. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know if SAS SQL has CTEs, I suppose it does)

The program below first normalises the cros table, then it recomputes the ranks of the cell values, then it uses the new ranks to update the original table.

(update is not strictly needed, in SAS it would probably be better to just create a new table for the result)

```
-- create the data
CREATE TABLE sasmeuk
        ( ref11 CHAR(1)
        , ref2 CHAR(1)
        , col1 INTEGER
        , col2 INTEGER
        , col3 INTEGER
        , col4 INTEGER
        , col5 INTEGER
        , col6 INTEGER
        );
INSERT INTO sasmeuk
( ref11, ref2, col1, col2, col3, col4,col5,col6) VALUES
 ('A', 'B',     41 ,NULL,   42,NULL,NULL,NULL)
 ,('D', 'E', NULL,    63 ,  65,NULL,   6,NULL)
 ,('X', 'Y',     23 ,  25 ,  55 ,NULL,  89,  99)
 ,('K', 'L',     12 ,NULL,NULL,   22,NULL,NULL)
 ,('U', 'V', NULL,NULL,    22,   88,NULL,  11)
        ;

-- SELECT * FROM sasmeuk;

WITH flat AS ( -- NORMALISE the cross-table
        SELECT ref11,ref2,1 AS idx, col1 AS val FROM sasmeuk
        UNION ALL SELECT ref11,ref2,2 AS idx, col2 AS val FROM sasmeuk
        UNION ALL SELECT ref11,ref2,3 AS idx, col3 AS val FROM sasmeuk
        UNION ALL SELECT ref11,ref2,4 AS idx, col4 AS val FROM sasmeuk
        UNION ALL SELECT ref11,ref2,5 AS idx, col5 AS val FROM sasmeuk
        UNION ALL SELECT ref11,ref2,6 AS idx, col6 AS val FROM sasmeuk
        )
, argh AS ( -- Compute new ranks.
        SELECT f.*
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY f.ref11,f.ref2 ORDER BY f.idx) AS rnk
        FROM flat f
        WHERE f.val IS NOT NULL
        )
, inflated AS ( -- DENORMALISE: rejoin with keys, and pick col[1-6] by ranks
        SELECT a0.ref11,a0.ref2
                , a1.val AS col1 , a2.val AS col2 , a3.val AS col3
                , a4.val AS col4 , a5.val AS col5 , a6.val AS col6
        FROM sasmeuk a0
        LEFT JOIN argh a1 ON a1.ref11 =  a0.ref11 AND a1.ref2  = a0.ref2 AND a1.rnk =1
        LEFT JOIN argh a2 ON a2.ref11 =  a0.ref11 AND a2.ref2  = a0.ref2 AND a2.rnk =2
        LEFT JOIN argh a3 ON a3.ref11 =  a0.ref11 AND a3.ref2  = a0.ref2 AND a3.rnk =3
        LEFT JOIN argh a4 ON a4.ref11 =  a0.ref11 AND a4.ref2  = a0.ref2 AND a4.rnk =4
        LEFT JOIN argh a5 ON a5.ref11 =  a0.ref11 AND a5.ref2  = a0.ref2 AND a5.rnk =5
        LEFT JOIN argh a6 ON a6.ref11 =  a0.ref11 AND a6.ref2  = a0.ref2 AND a6.rnk =6
        )
UPDATE sasmeuk dst -- Do the final update
SET col1 = src.col1 , col2 = src.col2 , col3 = src.col3
        , col4 = src.col4 , col5 = src.col5 , col6 = src.col6
FROM inflated src
WHERE src.ref11 = dst.ref11 AND src.ref2  = dst.ref2
        ;

SELECT * FROM sasmeuk
        ;
```

UPDATE: the code below is less elegant, but a lot simpler:

```
UPDATE sasmeuk SET col5 = col6, col6 = NULL WHERE col5 IS NULL;
UPDATE sasmeuk SET col4 = col5, col5 = NULL WHERE col4 IS NULL;
UPDATE sasmeuk SET col3 = col4, col4 = NULL WHERE col3 IS NULL;
UPDATE sasmeuk SET col2 = col3, col3 = NULL WHERE col2 IS NULL;
UPDATE sasmeuk SET col1 = col2, col2 = NULL WHERE col1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm afraid SAS does not support `CTE`s nor `PARTITION` yet! It would be great if they did.

Comment: IIRC, they do have CTE's (could be a version-thing) Not sure about WINDOW functions.

Comment: please could you post a link to CTEs in SAS SQL. I tried searching for them before but couldn't find it.